# Alternative ways of searching a string in mysql column

Tags: mysql, sql

I've a web app developed by java. Currently I'm in a part of my app that I need to use MySql `like` in order to search for a string in mysql table contain 100000+ rows. When I had my research I found that MySql `like` doesn't use indexes but if you have the wildcard at the end of your string example: `hello%` but I need `%hello%` which `like` doesn't use index in these kinds of wildcards. And I also read on the internet that there are other technologies such as postgresql which can give you the ability of using indexes for searching string.

My question is Just because of `like` do I need to change MySql DB with all it's other features to postgresql DB, Do we have any alternative way on MySql To search for a string that uses indexes?, Do I Install them both and use each for it's own use ( If there is no other way );

All replies are much appreciated.

Comment: If you want to search for substrings within a string (rather than *words*), then Postgres is a very viable option.  Personally, I find it more powerful than MySQL, so I wouldn't regret such a switch.

Comment: @gordonLinoff But I have a lot of MySql Queries running in my web app for retrieving information. Do I need to change them too?

Answer (score 0):

> Do we have any alternative way on MySql To search for a string

Have you looked into MySQL [`Full-Text Search`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fulltext-search.html) which uses fulltext index; provided you are using either  `InnoDB` or `MyISAM` engine

Comment: Yeah, Can't really use `Full-Text Search`

Comment: I'm using just mysql and not using any external engines.